# Is there any automated way of populating a Moodle training from a GitHub repository?

Tags: github, automation, moodle

Moodle is a platform for creating training and educational material. By default, it is possible to make the content by clicking on controls.

GitHub is a place for version management and teamwork.

Question: I wondered if there is a way to (programmatically) populate/update a Moodle training from a GitHub repository. Does Moodle offer an API that would allow the implementation of such a functionality?

Idea:

- The GitHub repository contains mark-down files in a specific format and folder structure.

Comment: What would the content in github be? Moodle has the concept of courses, with each course having activities, resources or modules. There are activities that can use external sources, such as "(LTI) External tool" and "SCORM", as well as resources such as Files, "IMS content package" and URLs

Comment: Pages + quizzes. Organized in a flat folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Theoretically. Moodle offers an API (https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions) through which you can update courses along with much other functionality.

You would have to write the script yourself, of course. I've been briefly looking in to this as well, but the moodle webservice API is not intuitive and is underdocumented. There's been talk of making a more sensible, RESTful API (https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-49607) but it doesn't seem to have gotten anywhere.